# 4 wireless controllers on pc or laptop (Couch Coop)

Tags: controllers, nba2k16, wwe-2k16

I just want to ask if its possible to use 4 wireless controllers on pc for NBA 2k16 or WWE from STEAM, and what are the controllers thats easy to use, like plug and play controllers example like xbox 360 wireless controller or xbox one wireless controller. Do i need a bluetooth receiver and how many receiver should I use for 4 controllers?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the type of receiver you are using. The official Microsoft devices allow you to connect multiple devices so it depends entirely on what controllers you are using.

I've personally used the Xbox One wireless receiver to play four player games (Party Saboteurs in this case) on a pc, and it worked like a charm.

If you are using an unofficial adapter, check the site out to ensure it allows multiple connections.

So in short: You will need the appropriate receiver, and just one will be fine.

Comment: Thank you sir, do you know what's the name of the official device from microsoft and how much? And will the xbox 360 works? (Cause you know its much affordable than xone)

Comment: It's remarkably hard to track down the stand alone adapter, but there is one that comes bundled with a controller if you don't already have four. [Controller and adapter](https://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msaus/en_AU/pdp/Xbox-360-Wireless-Controller-for-Windows-with-PC-USB-Adapter/productID.273183800).

Please keep in mind this is just to get the devices connected to your computer, the video game may not support multiple controllers.

[Adapter is available on amazon, apparently](https://www.amazon.com/dp/B000HZFCT2/?tag=stackoverfl08-20)